# Ionic v3 - disable "Take Video" in input type upload

Tags: cordova, video, ionic3

I'm developing a Ionic v3 APP that enables upload videos to my server. Right know, I have a HTML button that will call `this.videoInp.nativeElement.click()` and `this.videoInp` is a element like:

```
<input type="file" (change)="videoUpload($event)" id="file-input"
style="opacity: 0" accept="video/*" #videoInp>
```

This works fine in iOS, calling the native function that show 3 options to select the video to be upload.

1. Take Video
2. Photo Library
3. Browse

The image below ilustrates how this options are displayed:

[image: Imgur]

Everytime that I select Take Video, my APPS crashs. I want to fix this or either remove this option.

Comment: Are you get any solution. please help me.